# Zero-sum partition of an abelian group

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, abelian-groups

This is a question I have been asking myself some 5 years ago. I later got bored by lack of progress, but maybe some additive combinatorialists here know further. I'm not claiming it is conceptual or objectively interesting, but I wouldn't be surprised to see it studied by the likes of Erdös either.

**Question:** Let $G$ be a finite abelian group such that the sum of all elements of $G$ is zero. Let $n\neq 1$ be an integer such that $n\mid \left|G\right|-1$. Can we partition the set $G\setminus \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$ into disjoint $n$-element zero-sum subsets? (A subset of $G$ is said to be *zero-sum* if the sum of its elements is zero.)

*[Question corrected due to a remark by quid.]*

**Remarks:**

**1.** This has a definitely positive answer for $G = \left(\mathbb Z / \left(p\right)\right)^k$ with $p$ a prime and $k$ a positive integer. (In fact, the abelian group $\left(\mathbb Z / \left(p\right)\right)^k$ is isomorphic to the additive group of the finite field with $p^k$ elements; now you can take a primitive root $\zeta$ in this field, set $m=\dfrac{p^k-1}{n}$, and partition $G\setminus \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$ into the zero-sum subsets

$\left\lbrace \zeta^0, \zeta^{0+m}, ..., \zeta^{0+\left(n-1\right)m}\right\rbrace$,

$\left\lbrace \zeta^1, \zeta^{1+m}, ..., \zeta^{1+\left(n-1\right)m}\right\rbrace$,

...,

$\left\lbrace \zeta^{m-1}, \zeta^{m-1+m}, ..., \zeta^{m-1+\left(n-1\right)m}\right\rbrace$.)

**2.** In the general case, we can WLOG assume that $n$ is prime, but this doesn't seem to help (me).

Comment: You need to take care that p is not 2, or otherwise modify the conditions.  Otherwise there are no choices for n.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.19

Comment: I should add the words "Mersenne prime" to my previous comment.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.19

Comment: If there are no proper nontrivial divisors of |G|-1, the better... in this case the problem holds vacuously.

Comment: Also, this problem has a feel of projective geometry.  You might consider a solution involving a subset of a finite geometry.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.19

Comment: Is the case of $G$ cyclic easy?

Comment: Seva: good question, but none I can answer...

Comment: I find investigating the problem for small cyclic groups to be instructive (meaning it torpedoes my naive attempts for solving).  For example, for the cyclic group of order 13, starting with sets (1,2,-3), (-1,-2,-3) leads to an unhappy conclusion.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Exploratory Failures" Paseman, 2012.02.19

Comment: Can you solve $n=3$ when  $G = \mathbb Z / \left(5\right) \times \mathbb Z / \left(11\right)$? Cases $\mathbb Z / \left(p\right) \times \mathbb Z / \left(q\right)$ where $n$ divides both of $p-1, q-1$ are solved by patching together the partitions given by each prime. $\left|G\right| = 55$ is the smallest case for $n=3$ where this doesn't apply.
I haven't made it work, but I also can't say that it doesn't.

Comment: About the zero-sum assumption: We know that $G\sim({\mathbb Z}/(d_1))\times\cdots({\mathbb Z}/(d_r))$ with $d_1|d_2$, ..., $d_{r-1}|d_r$. Then the sum of all elements in $G$ equals zero unless one $d_\ell$ is even and all the other ones are odd.

Comment: @Denis Serre: yes, as I said, the two-rank must not be one. But you are right the explict form is helpful. Perhaps even more explcitly:  `$d_{r-1}$` is odd and `$d_r$` even.   


Comment: @Zack Wolske : A similar question arises for the group $\left( \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} \right) \times \left( \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} \right) .$ 

Comment: @Geoff: For that we have $(1,3,4), (2,9,13), (5,12,15), (6,8,10), (7,11,14)$. This comes from considering how many of each triple (either $(0,0,0)$ or $(0,1,1)$) we must use for $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$. There's only one option, and the rest of it falls into place. 
You're right, I wasn't considering even values, and I also don't know $\mathbb Z / \left(10\right) \times \mathbb Z / \left(4\right)$ for $n=3$ or $\mathbb Z / \left(18\right) \times \mathbb Z / \left(2\right)$ for $n=5$. They seem to boil down to finding positive solutions to underdetermined linear systems.

Comment: @Zack: Yes, I came at it from the point of view of the case $n =3$ and $G$ being an Abelian group of order congruent to 1 (mod $3$) which doe not admit an automorphism of order $3$, as in my modified answer below. Such a $G$ has pretty restricted structure. I thought the group of order $16$ would be OK, but I hadn't checked. I'm not sure how to be systematic in general.

Answer (score 8):

No. The sum of all (nonzero) elements of a finite abelian group is not necessarily $0$, which is however necessary for what you want.

A small counterexample would be the cyclic group with ten elements (and $n=3$).

Remark: To avoid this reason the sharp condition is to restrict to groups whose two-rank is not one.

Personal comment: sorry for the 'stupid answer'; not sure what happens with the suggested restriction in place, but seems interesting.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. "Stupid" as you claim it to be, it explains why most of my approaches failed! I have restricted the question now, as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

Answer rewritten in light of comments received: Original answer essentially did what Zack suggested in the case that $|G|$ was odd and $n$ was even, but in an unnecessarily complicated manner. This edit treats the suggested amendment by Will in a slightly different fashion. Suppose that $G$ admits an automorphism $\alpha$ of order prime order $n$ which fixes only $0$ (the additive identity of $G$). Denote $G \backslash \{ 0 \}$ by $G^{\#}.$ Then $G^{\#}$ is a disjoint union of orbits under $ \langle \alpha \rangle$, each of which has length $n$ by hypothesis. The sum across each of these orbits is zero because for any $g \in G$, the element $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha^{k}(g)$ is fixed by $\alpha$, so must be $0$ by assumption. This covers the case that $G$ has odd order, since in that case inversion is an automorphism which fixes only $0.$ It is not necessary to suppose that $\alpha$ has prime order. More generally, the argument works if each power of $\alpha$ other than the identity fixes only $0$.

Third edit: it may be of interest to note that this argument does not generalize directly to the case that $\alpha$ is an automorphism of prime order $n$ which has non-zero fixed points on $G$. If we could partition $G^{\#}$ into disjoint "zero-sum" sets of size $n,$ then we have $|G| \equiv 1$ (mod $n$), so certainly $n$ does not divide $|G|.$ By standard results on coprime automorphisms, we may wirt $G = H \oplus K$, where $H$ is the fixed-point subgroup of $\alpha$ and $K$ is an $\alpha$-invariant complement (in this special case, this can be proved in the same way as Maschke's theorem). Note that $|H| \equiv |G|$ (mod $n$), so that $H$ contains no element of order $n.$ Then for any non-zero element $h \in H$ and any $k \in K,$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^{i}(h +k) = n . h \neq 0.$ However, it does reduce the problem to finding a suitable partition of $H$ into zero-sum subsets of size $n.$ For example, if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_{i} = 0$ for distinct elements $ \{s_{1},s_{2},\ldots ,s_{n} \}$ of  $H$, then for each orbit of $\langle \alpha  
\rangle$ on $K^{\#}$, we can add the $i$-th element of the orbit to $s_i,$ and we get a zero sum subset of $G$ disjoint from  $ \{s_{1},s_{2},\ldots ,s_{n} \}$. Hence if we can partition $H^{\#}$ into disjoint  zero sum sets of size $n,$ we can do the same for $G^{\#}.$ Fourth Edit: It might be worth noting that when $n$ is prime, this reduces the problem in the case that $|G|$ is Abelian and $|G| \equiv 1$ (mod $n$) ( the latter case obviously being necessary if the desired partition is to exist) to the case that ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is group of order prime to $n.$ For if $G$ has an automorphism $\alpha$ of order $n,$ then we can work with the smaller group $C_{G}(\alpha)$ of fixed points of $\alpha$. If that group has a partition of the required form, so does $G.$ If the smaller groups still has an automorphism of order $n,$ then we can replace it by an even smaller group, and so on. If a finite Abelian group $G$ has no automorphism group of order $n,$ then (among other things) when it is decomposed as a direct summand of cyclic groups of prime power order, no $n-1$ summands can be mutually isomorphic.

Comment: For G odd, no element has order 2, hence we can pair each non-identity element with its inverse to get zero sum sets of size 2. For multiples of 2, combine the correct number of these pairs.

Comment: As I said, it is enough to consider the case of $n$ prime - this is so for the very reason Zack gave in his comment. Unfortunately I didn't get any farther than $n=2$ with this approach.

Comment: An obvious generalization is that if $n=p$ and the order of the group has only prime factors that are $1$ mod $p$, then you can set up multiplication by $p$th roots of unity and make this work.

Answer (score 2):

there is paper by Zeng about that : Zeng X., On zero-sum partitions of abelian groups. Integers 15 (2015), Paper No. A44, 16 pp.

Comment: Thanks -- but this doesn't settle the question in its general case, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Alexey Pokrovskiy and I addressed this problem for sufficiently large groups. See Section 1.1.2 and 6.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.09666.pdf